# Can't disable error logging in php5-fpm

Tags: php-fpm

Is there any way to disable error logging in `php5-fpm`?

I changed the `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` file with:

```
log_errors = Off
display_errors = Off
```

and restarted `php5-fpm`.

My `nginx` logfiles are still full of php warnings.

Comment: Did you check that was the ini file used by PHP?

Comment: I can't find another php.ini file

Comment: Don't search - simply create a page with phpinfo() on it. If you have got the right page, then check you're not overriding the behaviour via http config / .htaccess by adding a page which reports what values it sees using ini_get()

Comment: Please copy example of the error from the logfile

Answer (score 1):

Edit php-fpm.conf and set `error_log=` to empty, or /dev/null.

Comment: php-fpm.conf contains the following line error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log, but php warnings/errors are logged in /var/log/nginx/error.log

Answer (score 1):

It's Nginx that is logging these errors.

Taken from http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule:

> Note that error_log off does not disable logging - the log will be written to a file named "off". To disable logging, you may use:

`error_log /dev/null crit;`

in your nginx.conf file, usually located in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Check your php-fpm configuration for:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

And comment this out.

Comment: /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf doesn't contain these lines.

Comment: In my instalations there is directory called /etc/php-fpm.d check config files there for those two lines

Comment: I don't have this directory. It's something very strange. A few days ago installed php5-fpm+nging on another (dedicated) server and it doesn't log php warnings/errors. Yesterday I installed the same things on VPS and now this problem. Don't know how to solve it. Temporary solution is ini_set('log_errors', 0);

Answer (score 0):

It's Nginx not php who write this log. You need to edit your nginx config to log only critical error (note that you cannot disable error logging, but you can change the log level). And note that you should fix errors instead of hide them ^^